# Understanding the fundamentals of building an in-Memory Distributed Graph

Tags: graphs, data-structures, reference-request, distributed-systems

I am working on a project where I have to build an in-memory distributed graph capturing the relation between similar files(based on some similarity metric) stored in shared file system over multiple nodes in a network.

I know basic graph data structure. I googled to know about distributed graph, but what I found mostly is just an info about existing distributed graph databases like titan, FlockDB etc. But I really couldn't find any fundamental guide to building a distributed graph or in general explaining a basic algorithm of building a distributed graph.

Can you please suggest few references where I can get such material explaining the fundamentals.

Comment: This could potentially be a bit broad.  What research have you done? Why have you rejected existing distributed graph databases?  Have you tried looking for information about what data structures and algorithms they use?  Are there some specific requirements you have that they don't satisfy?

Comment: No I am not rejecting existing distributed databases. I just want to know the fundamental concepts of building distributed graph that these databases are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the *Cloud Computing* area - there is a lot of research about graphs representation and processing there.

For example, [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/131014/Surfer_tr.pdf).